# How to solve cycle equations in Group Theory? Is my approach correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I am studying Abstract Algebra on my own so I don't know if there are gaps in my knowledge. I didn't find any example to solve the following equation in my reference textbook.
Find ${\tau\in S_7, \text{such that } \sigma'=\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} \text{ where } \sigma=(125)(3674), \sigma'=(314)(2765)}$
I tried the following.
Right multiplication by ${\tau}$ and left multiplication by ${\sigma'^{-1}}$ gives ${\tau=\sigma'^{-1}\tau\sigma}$
${\implies \tau=(341)(2765)^3\tau(125)(3674)}$
I tried the following approach.
$\tau(1)=(341)(2765)^3\tau(\sigma(1))=(341)(2765^3)\tau(2)$
$\tau(2)=(341)(2765)^3\tau(\sigma(2))=(341)(2765)^3\tau(5)$
$\tau(5)=(341)(2765)^3\tau(\sigma(5))=(341)(2765)^3\tau(1)$
If I back substitute the values, I get
$\tau(2)=(341)^2(2765)^6\tau(1) \therefore\tau(1)=(2765)\tau(1)$
Is this approach correct? Am I close? How do I proceed forward?

One observation I made was if $\tau(1)\in\{2,5,6,7\}, $ then the equation cannot be satisfied. Therefore, $\tau(1)\in\{3,4,1\}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Think of conjugation as a "change of basis".

So $(125) $ must be mapped to $(314)$.

---

In fact, for every "change of basis", we have such a conjugation.
What is the conjugation that maps 1 to 3, 2 to 1, 5 to 4, 3 to 2, 6 to 7, 7 to 6 and 4 to 5?

> $ 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1, 4 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 4, 6 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 6$.
>  Hence, this is $ (132) (45)(67)$.

What is we wanted to mix it up so that we map 1 to 1, 2 to 4, 5 to 3, 3 to 6, 6 to 5, 7 to 2, 4 to 7?

> $ 1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 3$.
>  Hence, this is $ (1)(247)(365)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I figured out the solution. I tried $\tau(1)=1$ and found the correct answer on my second attempt. Is there an analytic approach instead of starting with trying various combinations that map (1,2,5) to (3,1,4).

Comment: @SaquibMohammad Do you understand what it means to think of conjugation as a change of basis? The analytical way of solving this problem is what I said down below. In fact, there are exactly 12 conjugations that work (Do you see why?)

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. I didn't pay that much attention to the wording. Now that I looked at the structure of the equations and gave it a bit of thought, it made sense. By basis, we mean "transforming maps" if I got it right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Most likely yes (but it's hard to know for certain what you think of a "transforming map"). I've added the conjugations that are needed, which is just formalizing the information.

Comment: I was thinking, based on the equation/structure of $\tau(1),\tau(2),\tau(5)$ that (1,2,5) has to go to (3,1,4) (As you also hinted in the answer.)
So $1\mapsto 3...$
Second part for ${\tau(3),\tau(4),\tau(7),\tau(6)}$ should be mapped to (2,5,6,7). Hence $3\mapsto 2, 4\mapsto 5..$ and so on. So I thought of this $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \mapsto (3,1,2,5,4,6,7)$