# Find $\tau \in A_6$ such that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, self-learning

Let $$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 4&5&2&1&6&3\end{pmatrix}\in S_6.$$ Then $\sigma = (1\text{ }4)(2\text{ }5\text{ }6\text{ }3)$ and thus $\sigma^{-1}=(4\text{ }1)(3\text{ }6\text{ }5\text{ }2)$. Then ${\rm sgn}(\sigma)={\rm sgn}(\sigma^{-1})=1\Rightarrow \sigma,\sigma^{-1}\in A_6$. I now have to find $\tau \in A_6$ such that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$.

I know that $$\tau=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 4&3&2&1&6&5\end{pmatrix}$$ solves it since $$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}=(\tau(1)\tau(4))(\tau(2)\tau(5)\tau(6)\tau(3))=(4\text{ }1)(3\text{ }6\text{ }5\text{ }2)=\sigma^{-1},$$but $\tau \not \in A_6$ and this is where I'm stuck.

Am I going in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Drop the (14). You do not need it. [(14)=(41)].

Comment: Ah yes of course, since $(1\text{ }4)=(4\text{ }1)$ right? Just saw your edit, thank you!

Comment: You have got it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve cycle equations in Group Theory? Is my approach correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459993/how-to-solve-cycle-equations-in-group-theory-is-my-approach-correct)